# How do I use SetTile() with a tile asset/ scriptable tile?

Tags: unity, c#, tilemap

How do I use `Tilemap.SetTile()` with a tile asset? I want to use it for scriptable tiles in the 2d-extras package, such as rule tiles, weighted random tiles, and animated tiles.

How would I...

1. get inspector reference of this scriptable tile, and then
2. use `SetTile()` with it?

Comment: Presumably you tried exposing a `public Tile myTileToSet;` variable in your script, and calling `SetTile` with that variable? What went wrong when you tried that?

Comment: @DMGregory i have tried that, but i don't think the `RuleTile` inherits `Tile`, so I cannot assign the inspector reference.

Comment: `RuleTile` inherits from `TileBase`, which is what `SetTile` accepts, so you tried using that as the type of your variable, yes?

Comment: To clarify, normaly when i drag a sprite into the tile palette, it creates a `Tile` object in the project folder. I can then assign that into a `Tile` variable. However, when i drag in a scriptable tile such as a rule tile into the tile palette, no tile object is created. I tried dragging the rule tile scriptable object into the exposed `Tile` variable, yet it does not allow me to

Comment: I think `TileBase` worked, thanks for the help!

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer below. In future, don't forget to read the documentation for the functions you're using to find what argument type you need.

Answer (score -1):

TileBase actualy works, so i recommend using it.

Comment: Can you show in more detail how you used TileBase to solve this problem?